# Using $_get on URL that is linked to id in database row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to $_get part of URL in a href. What I want to happen is when you click the link you a redirected to that specific link. If that makes sense.

I have 2 functions:

First function, The list of links:

```
function showPosts() {
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM blog");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $listId = $row["blog_id"];
        $showTitle = $row["title"];
        $showContent = $row["content"];
        $showTimestamp = $row["timestamp"];
        
        echo'
            <div>
            <a href="index.php?option=blog&task=view&id='.$listId.'"><h3>'.$showTitle.'</h3></a>
                <div>'.$showContent.'</div>
                <p>'.$showTimestamp.'</p>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

Second function, redirect to link:

```
function viewPost() {
    
    if(empty($_GET['id']) ) {
        $listId = '';   
    } else {
        $listId = $_GET['id'];
    }
    
    $sql = ("SELECT title, content, timestamp FROM blog WHERE blog_id='.$listId.'");
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $showTitle = $row["title"];
        $showContent = $row["content"];
        $showTimestamp = $row["timestamp"];
        
        echo'
            <div>
                <h2>'.$showTitle.'</h2>
                <p>'.$showTimestamp.'</p>
                <div>'.$showContent.'</div>
            </div>
        ';
    }
}
```

As you can see i'm using $_get['id'] here and I read that $_get can be used to retrieve passed url parameters.

The way i have set up the URL is defined by a set of variables in a switch.

```
if(empty($_GET['task']) ) {
    $task = 'show'; 
} else {
    $task = $_GET['task'];
}


switch ($task){
    case "create":
        createPost();
        die();          
        break;
    case "save":
        savePost();
        die();
        break;
    case "show":
        showPosts();
        die();
        break;
    case "view":
        viewPost();
        die();
        break;
    default:    echo'Something went wrong!';
}
```

Currently when I click a link, it redirects but all of the content related to that id is not there.

Comment: You should switch to mysqli or PDO. Refer to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Yeah I know that. I'm just trying to figure out functions before I look into security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing the die() command in the switch. Die command is used to handle errors, it stops immediately the script execution and returns the error message set as argument. Try removing it.

Comment: Remove all of the die's?

Comment: Yes. If I understand your code correctly you currently should be getting a white page upon visiting the link.

Comment: Yepp. It seemed like that and one other thing was the problem here. Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Make sure you typecast your input to an integer